# C# writing to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application that write some information to XML file here it is:

```
private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    openedFilePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    XmlWriterSettings set = new XmlWriterSettings();
    set.Indent = true;
    set.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName, set))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Tree");
        writer.WriteStartElement("languages");
        foreach (TabPage page in textTC.TabPages)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("language");
            writer.WriteElementString("lan", page.Text);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("variables");
        foreach (Variable v in Form4.variables)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("variableOut");
            writer.WriteElementString("varName", v.varName);

            if (v.type == VariableType.BOOL)
                writer.WriteElementString("type", "bool");

            if (v.type == VariableType.INT)
                writer.WriteElementString("type", "int");

            writer.WriteElementString("value", v.value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        foreach (TabPage page in textTC.TabPages)
        {

            writer.WriteStartElement(page.Text);
            writer.WriteStartElement("phrases");

            for (int i = 0; i < dialogElements.Count; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("phrase");
                writer.WriteElementString("ID", dialogElements[i].ID);
                writer.WriteElementString("indexInBranch", dialogElements[i].indexInBranch.ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("characterName", dialogElements[i].characterName);
                writer.WriteElementString("text", dialogElements[i].dialogText);
                writer.WriteElementString("choiceText", dialogElements[i].choiceText);
                writer.WriteElementString("fileName", dialogElements[i].fileName);
                writer.WriteElementString("jumpTo", dialogElements[i].jumpTo.ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("idToJump", dialogElements[i].idToJump);
                writer.WriteElementString("soundsFolder", soundsFolder);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("elements");

            for (int i = 0; i < Form5.operationsOfElements.Count; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("element");
                writer.WriteElementString("ID", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].id);

                for (int j = 0; j < Form5.operationsOfElements[i].setElems.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("SET");
                    writer.WriteElementString("variable", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].setElems[j].variable);
                    writer.WriteElementString("operation", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].setElems[j].operation);
                    writer.WriteElementString("value", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].setElems[j].value);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < Form5.operationsOfElements[i].checkElems.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("CHECK");
                    writer.WriteElementString("variable", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].checkElems[j].variable);
                    writer.WriteElementString("condition", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].checkElems[j].condition);
                    writer.WriteElementString("value", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].checkElems[j].value);
                    writer.WriteElementString("xmlFile", Form5.operationsOfElements[i].checkElems[j].xmlFile);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

Initially it was working perfectly. But when I added some more elements it begun to give me an error like this:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Writing StartElement when EndRootElement is called will produce invalid XML document. In order to be able to write fragmentXML ConformanceLevel should have property of ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto.

Exception is raised in this line: writer.WriteStartElement(page.Text);

Comment: if you replace all string variables in your code to const strings, will error still be exist?

Comment: you likely have one or more WriteEndElement too many

Comment: Rune FS I also think so. I have added "languages" block. So this might be a key. Before "languages" block it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are wrongly ended the languages inside the for each loop..it should come outside the loop

from down 5th line WriteEndElement(); cut it and past it out side of the close bracket (3rd one from down) past before writer.WriteEndDocument();

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have an incorrect number of WriteEndElement calls. If you can find the line in the code from the exception this will help you find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exception handling in the method example as provided. Add `try except` and use the debugger to see where the exception is raised.

Comment: writer.WriteStartElement(page.Text); here is the exception source.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for helping. I have found my mistake. There were two extra WriteEndElements(); in 3rd block!